# Extend UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I beginner in iOS. I try extend UILocalNotification. My class below.

```
@interface FSCustomNatification : UILocalNotification

typedef enum {
    FSCustomNatificationPay,
    FSCustomNatificationWrite,
    FSCustomNatificationSend
} NotificationTypeT;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NotificationTypeT typeNotificationT;


@end



#import "FSCustomNatification.h"

@implementation FSCustomNatification



@end
```

When I set typeNotificationT property I get -[UIConcreteLocalNotification setTypeNotificationT:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8144780. Why?

```
FSCustomNatification* localNotification = [[FSCustomNatification alloc] init];
localNotification.typeNotificationT = FSCustomNatificationWrite;
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `init`? It looks like it thinks `localNotification` is a `UIConcreteLocalNotification` rather than a `FSCustomNatification `. Also, you have an a instead of an o in your class name.

Comment: Yes, I tried overrite init.

Answer (score 6):

By the looks of your error message `UILocalNotification` is part of a class cluster. The docs don't say (that I can see quickly) but it seems unlikely that you should subclass `UILocalNotification`.

Instead, you should make use of the `userInfo` provided by `UILocalNotification` to add any extra information you want to be available when the notification fires.