# How to access properties of my subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, subclass, uilocalnotification

I have a subclass of UILocalNotification:

The .h-file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MRLocalNotification : UILocalNotification

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *UUID;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger calendarUnit;
@property int frequency;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
#import "MRLocalNotification.h"

@implementation MRLocalNotification

@end
```

When I create an instance and set a property in my  view controller, I am getting SIGABRT and this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIConcreteLocalNotification setUUID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175f5c60'

Here is how I create and set the property:

```
    MRLocalNotification *notification = [[MRLocalNotification alloc] init];
    [notification setUUID:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]];
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Not sure if this is the only correct answer, but I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317860/extend-uilocalnotification

Comment: A more complete answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8583329/2708650

Answer (score 0):

Does dot notation work? ie:

```
notification.UUID = @"string"
```

you shouldn't need to do this but add synthesizers in the .m file

```
@syntheisze UUID
```

Compiler adds synthesizers for you if left blank

Also are you overriding the setter method in the .m file?

Comment: no, tried that, and synthesizing and anything I can think of. Obviously Ian MacDonald's link is correct

Comment: Try deleting the file and recreating it

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583329/3899770

`-alloc` is overriden by `UILocalNotification` to always return `UILocalNotification` objects.